# How to change border-radius of progress bar value?

Tags: html, css, progress-bar

I'm having trouble changing the border-radius of the value of an HTML5 `<progress>` element. I try applying a border radius to the progress element itself and to `progress[value]`, but that doesn't seem to do anything.

So I want the progress bar value to look something like this: [image]

Instead of this: [image]

Here is what I have so far: https://jsfiddle.net/8m93Lorn/1/

Any ideas?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To do so you need to do it like so:

It seems like these are duplicates, but this actually makes sure that it works across all browsers

```
progress {
    border: 0;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 20px;
}
progress::-webkit-progress-bar {
    border: 0;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 20px;
}
progress::-webkit-progress-value {
    border: 0;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 20px;
}
progress::-moz-progress-bar {
    border: 0;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 20px;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/98f0gpg0/)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Why are there two `progress::-webkit-progress-bar` selectors?

Comment: @RalphDavidAbernathy It's one `progress::-webkit-progress-bar` and one `progress::-webkit-progress-value` selector (inside and outside of the bar)

Comment: Ah ok, makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: @RalphDavidAbernathy No problem, glad to be able to help!

Answer (score 5):

use this code , in my chrome works

```
progress[value]::-webkit-progress-bar {
  background-color: #ededed;
  border-radius: 40px;
}

progress[value]::-webkit-progress-value {
  border-radius: 40px;
  background-color:lightblue;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8m93Lorn/2/

Comment: Thanks! The above accepted answer is not working for!