# How do I round the corners of a HTML progress bar?

Tags: css

I know you round corners with border-radius, **but it works like this with a progress bar:**

```html
<html>
<progress value="50" max="100" min="0" class="progress1">
    </progress>
<style>
.progress1 {
width:500px;
height:100px;
background-color: red;
        border-radius: 10px;
}
progress::-webkit-progress-value {
    background: red; 
        border-radius: 10px;
}
    </style>
</html>
```

**I've tested** **with a few browsers**, and so far it only does what I want it to do on Internet Explorer. I want the actual background of the progress in the progress bar to get rounded, not the actual progress.

Comment: This might solve the trick [How to change border-radius of progress bar value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34798069/how-to-change-border-radius-of-progress-bar-value).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following seems to work for your case:

```html
<html>
<progress value="50" max="100" min="0" class="progress1"></progress>
<style>
  .progress1 {
    width: 500px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    border-radius: 10px;
  }
  
  progress::-webkit-progress-bar {
    width: 500px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 10px;
  }
  
  progress::-webkit-progress-value {
    background-color: red;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  }
  
  progress::-moz-progress-bar {
    width: 500px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    border-radius: 10px;
  }
</style>

</html>
```

The [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4ybz2vod/2/)

Modified from to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34798353/12539335)

Comment: yeah, no problem @Technot